# How to use Windows 8 run time class MediaCapture into WPF app to show web cam preview?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-runtime

I am developing Windows 8 WPF desktop app. I need to preview webcam into my app. I come to know that MediaCapture class allows this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) but I am not able to use MediaCapture classs into WPF app any idea, any help how to do this ? Thanks.

Update: I am using following code and it crashes:

```
 async private void StartWebCamPrev()
    {
        Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture mediaCapture = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your original question and add in any relevant code, errors/exceptions you're seeing, etc. Thanks!

Comment: When is `StartWebCamPrev` being called? Also, change `async void` to `async Task` unless `StartWebCamPrev` is an event handler.

Comment: at any time you can call but in my app, it is called in button click.

Comment: There's a working example here: https://github.com/mmaitre314/MediaCaptureWPF, from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31506614/52068).

Answer (score -1):

The Windows.* namespaces belong to Windows Runtime (WinRT). Most of WinRT UI APIs are not available for desktop/WPF/.NET applications, so your approach won't work. You can use almost any other technique to display webcam preview, since WPF apps can integrate with a lot of other technologies - DirectShow being most notable. I would start with [WPF MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit).

Comment: Not quite: Almost 50% of the winrt APIs are available for desktop apps.  Unfortunately almost none of the APIs that show UI are available for desktop aps :(.

Comment: Maybe - every winrt API is tagged and the documentation for the API shows if it works on the desktop or not. For instance the Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket class says "Applies to: Metro style apps | desktop apps"

Comment: Ahh, yes. Now I can see that.

Comment: There is a list of new desktop APIs here that I would assume mostly includes WinRT APIs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920511(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I haven't seen however any document on how to use WinRT APIs from say .NET. I found some blog post here: "http://ermau.com/using-winrt-from-net/", but I can't find the winmd files where they used to be. What did I miss?

Comment: @Flip Thanks. You mean to say there is no control or way which can take feed from "StartPreviewAsync" ? I have noticed that in Metro app there is "CaptureElement" in XAML which directly takes i/p from "StartPreviewAsync" and works fine. I am looking for similar control or way in WPF.

Comment: If you check the documentation for [CaptureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx) - you'll see it says: "**Applies to:** Metro style apps only". You need to use another method in WPF - e.g. the WPF MediaKit.

Comment: Thanks Flip. I am thinking to use DirectShow as not want to use any third-party. Do you have any idea on how I can use DirectShow into WPF(C#) ?

Comment: I've never done it. I would check how it's done in WPF MediaKit. I am almost sure it does not use any patentable algorithms since it has got to be just wrapping some native APIs into WPF controls. You could ask [Jeremiah](http://twitter.com/jmorrill) who created it for help. Otherwise I would start digging into [DirectShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) or perhaps the newer [Media Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Foundation) (if you don't care about Windows XP).

Comment: @Flip I was just thinking that: If there is no way to use "MediaCapture" into WPF/Desktop app then why MS has provided support for "MediaCapture"  for desktop type app. There should be some reason for this.