# MediaCapture Windows 8 Desktop Application- Can't get it work

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps, webcam

I'm trying to implement an image capture via this API, and I need to implement in via desktop application.

The problem is that when I save the image into a file (with `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync`) I get a dark picture (almost black), or I get zero size file.

My code is very simple though:

```
MediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

Windows.Storage.StorageFile photoStorageFile;
String PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "photo.jpg";
photoStorageFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(PHOTO_FILE_NAME, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, photoStorageFile);
```

I read another thread about it:
[Captured photos are black when using MediaCapture on Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301513/captured-photos-are-black-when-using-mediacapture-on-windows-phone-8-1)

The problem is that `MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync` raised an exception "An unexpected error has occured in the operation requested", and I guess the reason for that is the MediaElement which I don't have (again, desktop).

I'll also glad to find a working example, when I searched, I didn't find any real sample to implement MediaCapture on desktop application, I saw an article but without attached code:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/10/29/how-to-use-specific-winrt-api-from-desktop-apps-capturing-a-photo-using-your-webcam-into-a-wpf-app.aspx

I also found that others also asked about a sample, but with no real answer...

How can I get a working sample for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `MediaCapture` to preview the camera video in Desktop apps is not trivial. I wasn't sure all the pieces were there so I put together some code on GitHub to try it out and it seems to work ok.

https://github.com/mmaitre314/MediaCaptureWPF

One caveat: building the MediaCapture/WPF interop required some native code (C++/CLI), so the app needs to be built as either x86 or x64, but not AnyCPU.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu! I wonder if it's possible to implement it all in C#?

Comment: So far I haven't found a C#-only way. WPF needs some kind of CaptureElement, which relies on DirectX and Media Foundation. They have some C# projection (SharpDX, etc.), so maybe there is a way to translate the C++ code into C#.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your store app to interact with the Camera there are actually two ways, a simple one, and an advanced one:

- Either by using the provided user interface, which is a common UI used to capture Media and it save you the pain of handling the basic capture operations,
- Or by interacting with the MediaCapture API yourself to gain complete control over the entire flow of operations.

if you just want to take a picture or a video from the
webcam, i suggest you use the first approach which mainly use the `CameraCaptureUI` API, but if you need complete control over the capturing operation, you need some lines of codes that interact with the `MediaCapture` APIs

here a simple example using the CameraCaptureUI API :

let say we have the following UI:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Click="TakePicture_Click" Content="Capture Photo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3">
            <Image x:Name="Picture" Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>            
    </StackPanel>
```

and here the capture button click handler:

```
private async void TakePicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
        var image = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        if (image != null)
        {
            var stream = await image.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(stream);
            Picture.Source = bitmap;
        }
        else
        {
            (new MessageDialog("Something went wrong")).ShowAsync();                
        }
    }
```

you need also to offer your app the permission to use the webcam by checking the Webcam capability in the App Manifest

[image]

Comment: Thanks but CameraCaptureUI is not supported on **Desktop** app.

Comment: What you mean Desktop app ??, CameraCaptureUI works great in winrt/store apps !!, i can give you a MediaCapture sample if yu want ?

Comment: Read the following article: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/windows-8-desktop-app-vs-store-app.htm . I can't work with store apps due to some reasons, so I need to work with desktop app (The new name of Winform/WPF/Console application). I really appreciate your effort in your answer but it's not the platform I can use.